# Integrating Stripe PHP library into a custom Wordpress Plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I am trying to create a simple 'add monthly Subscriptions(Monthly payments) button' custom plugin for a clients Wordpress website. My current issue is how am I to include Stripe's PHP library in the plugin? I have Stripe operational running it through Composer (autoload.php) locally. But adding it to Wordpress....

I have added the basic code from Stripe's website below:
https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/subscription-signup

```
 <form action="/create_subscription.php" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_mlHAlLZMWfb2URJZIvb6Qntd"
    data-image="/images/marketplace.png"
    data-name="Emma's Farm CSA"
    data-description="Subscription for 1 weekly box"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-label="Sign Me Up!">
  </script>
</form>
```

This is the PHP.

```
<?php // Create a customer using a Stripe token

// If you're using Composer, use Composer's autoload:
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

// Be sure to replace this with your actual test API key
// (switch to the live key later)
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_000000000000");

try
{
  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    'email' => $_POST['stripeEmail'],
    'source'  => $_POST['stripeToken'],
    'plan' => 'weekly_box'
  ));

  header('Location: thankyou.html');
  exit;
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  header('Location:oops.html');
  error_log("unable to sign up customer:" . $_POST['stripeEmail'].
    ", error:" . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this article](https://pippinsplugins.com/stripe-integration-part-1-building-the-settings-and-a-simple-payment-form/). It's kind of old, but still quite relevant - I used it to build my own Stripe integration plugin for Wordpress.

Note that including the line:

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
```

should load the Stripe libraries for you. Depending on how you have your plugin folders set up, the plugin might not be finding the autoload.php file. It's best to set a base directory in your plugin's primary php file as such:

```
if ( ! defined( 'PLUGINNAME_BASE_DIR' )) 
    define( 'PLUGINNAME_BASE_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ) );
```

Then, your require statement would look like:

```
require_once( PLUGINNAME_BASE_DIR . '/vendor/autoload.php' );
```

Even better, put the Stripe library in a /lib folder in your plugin, so your include would be:

```
require_once( PLUGINNAME_BASE_DIR . '/lib/stripe-php/vendor/autoload.php' );
```

There is also an [init.php](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/init.php) file in the library that does the same thing and is what I used since I didn't use Composer to pull it in. You can use this by downloading the source for the stripe-php library and putting the raw source in your plugin directory inside a /lib directory.

```
require_once( PLUGINNAME_BASE_DIR . '/lib/stripe-php/init.php' );
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I did come across Pippins website. Suppose my main issue is loading stripes most recent version 5.8.0. Using pippins code the older version of Stripe loads fine on a live Wordpress website.        `if(!defined('STRIPE_BASE_URL')) {
 define('STRIPE_BASE_URL', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__));
}
if(!defined('STRIPE_BASE_DIR')) {
 define('STRIPE_BASE_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));
}

require_once( STRIPE_BASE_URL . 'stripe/init.php' );

$stripe_options = get_option('stripe_settings');
`